# Formik form rerender on props change

Tags: reactjs, formik

Dears,
I have following component which is responsible for form rendering based on transaction type. For expenses and incomes. Both objects have the same structure. So the form will look the same for both but only dropdowns for categories and subcategories would be different.

```
const TransactionHandlingForm = props => {
    const [categoriesToBeDisplayed, setCategoriesToBeDisplayed] = useState("incomeTypes")
    const [initialValues, setInitialValues] = useState(props.initialValues)
    const handleSourceChange = (name) => {
      switch(name){
        case 'Income':
          setCategoriesToBeDisplayed('incomeTypes');
          setInitialValues({ ...initialValues, comment: 'yo' });
          break;
        case 'Expense':
          setInitialValues({...initialValues, comment: 'xo'})
          setCategoriesToBeDisplayed('expenseTypes');
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
    };

    return (
      <Content>
        <Container>
          <Grid container spacing={3}>
            <Grid item xs={12} align="right">
              <StyledCloseSign />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} align="left">
              {`${props.type === 'modified' ? 'MODIFY' : 'NEW'} TRANSACTION`}
            </Grid>
            {props.type === 'add' && renderNavigation(handleSourceChange)}
          </Grid>
          {renderForm({
            initialValues: initialValues,
            categories: props[categoriesToBeDisplayed],
            currencies: props.currencies
          })}
        </Container>
      </Content>
    );
};
```

The issue is I do not know how to smartly refresh Formik form.
When in navigation I will change type of added income **old values remains inside form**.
I have it done by changing initial values but don't think it is the best approach.

Component renderForm:

```
const renderForm = ({ initialValues, categories, currencies, handleChange }) => {
  return (
    <Formik
      enableReinitialize
      initialValues={initialValues}
      validationSchema={validations.getTransactionAdditionValidationSchema}
    >
      {({ setFieldValue, values }) => {
        return (
          <>
            <Grid container spacing={3}>
              <Grid item xs={8}>
                <LabelWrapper label={'Amount'}>
                  <InputWithBorder
                    id="amount"
                    name="amount"
                    type="text"
                    autoComplete="off"
                    placeholder="amount"
                    type="number"
                    step="0.5"
                  />
                </LabelWrapper>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={4}>
                <LabelWrapper label="Currency">
                  <Dropdown
                    name="currency"
                    list={currencies}
                    isSearchable={true}
                    label="Select Currency"
                    value={currencies.filter((currency) => {
                      return currency.id === values['currency_id']
                        ? currency.value
                        : '';
                    })}
                    onChange={(selectedOption) => {
                      setFieldValue('currency', selectedOption.value);
                      setFieldValue('currency_id', selectedOption.id);
                    }}
                  />
                </LabelWrapper>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <LabelWrapper label="Select category">
                  <Dropdown
                    name="category"
                    list={categories}
                    isSearchable={true}
                    isLoading={false}
                    value={values.category ? { label: values.category } : ''}
                    onChange={(selectedOption) => {
                      setFieldValue('category', selectedOption.value);
                    }}
                  />
                </LabelWrapper>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <LabelWrapper label="Select subcategory">
                  <Dropdown
                    name="subcategory"
                    list={getSubcategories({
                      category: values.category,
                      dependencies: categories,
                    })}
                    value={
                      values.subcategory ? { label: values.subcategory } : ''
                    }
                    onChange={(selectedOption) => {
                      setFieldValue('category_id', selectedOption.id);
                      setFieldValue('subcategory', selectedOption.value);
                    }}
                  />
                </LabelWrapper>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <LabelWrapper label={'Write a note'}>
                  <TextArea name={'comments'} />
                </LabelWrapper>
              </Grid>
              <Button type="submit">
                <StyledAddIcon />
                Add
              </Button>
            </Grid>
          </>
        );
      }}
    </Formik>
  );
};
```

Comment: Dears, Any ideas ?